# how can i fix this error: argument of type 'module' is not iterable (line 13)

Tags: python, module, pygame, runtime-error

when i run the program, is dont work properly, it only appear a black window, then i see that:
...line 13, in 
if event.type in pygame == pygame.QUIT:
Type Error: argument of type 'module' is not iterable

```
#Code
import pygame
    
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,600))
    GREY = (120,120,120)
    WHITE = (255,225,255)
    running = True
    while running:
        screen.fill(GREY)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (100,50,50,50))
            
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type in pygame == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            if event.type in pygame == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    print("X")
        pygame.display.flip()
    
        pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to compare `event.type` with `pygame.QUIT`:

<s>`if event.type in pygame == pygame.QUIT:`</s>

```py
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
```